# Setting React component props in a Styled Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am using styled components to enhance the looks of some of the basic material-ui React components. I want to be able to pass props into the MUI component, and then apply CSS styling via styled components.

As you can see, you are able to change the color of the item through styled components.

```
import MUICircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgess"
    
export const LoadingIcon = styled(MUICircularProgess)`
  color:black;
`
```

However, if I want to make the item larger, I need to pass `size` as Props to `MUICircularProgess`

How would one do this and is this is even possible?

If not, what are some possible workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.attr(...)` constructor to customize props being passed. Your code might need to be updated to something like this

```js
import MUICircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgess"
    
export const LoadingIcon = styled(MUICircularProgess).attr(props => ({
  size: '5rem', // or, size: props.size
}))`
  color:black;
`
```

For more reference, check official documentation [Attaching additional props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props)

```js
const {
  CircularProgress
} = MaterialUI

const Loader = styled(CircularProgress).attrs(props => ({
  size: '5rem',
}))
`
  color: black !important;
`

ReactDOM.render( <Loader /> , document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-is@17.0.2/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: This is it. In my case, I wasn't relying on props, just a hard-coded value, so my component looked like... styled(MUICircularProgress).attrs({size: 90}). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You simply pass a prop `size` to the component created using styled-components. e.g.,

```
<LoadingIcon size={14} />
```

This gives your LoadingIcon a prop of `size` whose value is 14. To use it,

```
export const LoadingIcon = styled(MUICircularProgess)`
  color:black;
  height: ${props => props.size || 10} //Apply it to any CSS property you like. I like to keep a fallback value, hence the || 10
`
```

[Source: styled-components official documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props)

Comment: this one is actually simpler than the accepted answers, not sure why this was skipped